# How to redirect old file urls using TYPO3 v9

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

Currently a TYPO3 website of ours has had a complete revamp and we would like to redirect all the old URL's in Googles index to the new existing URL's

For regular pages I used the new site management tool (Redirects) in TYPO3 v9. However what is left is the old indexed links of the content.

www.websitename.com/content/docs/this-is-my-document.pdf and so on. Including images and other miscellaneous links to files.

Now what would be the best way to redirect those links?

I could use htaccess ofcourse or is there something in the TYPO3 core/Extbase what I could be able to use?

Answer (score 2):

I would always prefer redirects with mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file since it's much faster than any TYPO3 solution. If the redirect is done via .htaccess, there is no need for the webserver to invoke PHP or the database. Thus it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Found out we stopped rewrites by default for URL's with:

```
RewriteRule ^(typo3/|content/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
```

By removing the 'content/' I was able to use the redirect functionality from the core. This was done so we could manage redirects through the TYPO3 enviroment in the future.

as Peter said above it would be faster to use .htaccess but we would like for it to be more manageable in the future through the system. So we chose the core option.